# how a method with string as its parameter in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, immutability

This below code compiles and works out as intended.

```
    class MyClass1
    {
        public void test()
        {
            string one = "testString1";
            Console.WriteLine("MyClass1: " + one);
            new MyClass2().test(one);
            Console.WriteLine(one); //again testString1 is printed.
        }

    }

class MyClass2
{
    public void test(string two)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test method");
        Console.WriteLine(two);
        two = "pilot";
        Console.WriteLine(two);
    }
}
```

all I infer from this is:

The value assigned to the string in `test` method is `local to that function` and the changes will be reflected only if I use a `ref or out`.

The question is:

We all know that the string is a `reference` type (because it is of type, String)

So, for all the `reference types` : when passing around their objects, the changes should be reflected right ? (For ex, for the same example, if I pass around a object of a class, then any changes are reflected back right ?)

Why is this rule not followed here ?

Can any one point me in understanding what happens under the hood ?

Comment: Here - http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: @shahkalpesh: cool article. was helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although strings are reference objects, they are also immutable. Since references are passed by value <sup>*</sup>, changes to variables representing the reference, are not reflected on the original.

To demonstrate the effect of passing reference objects, replace `string` with `StringBuilder`, and change the content inside the `test` method:

```
class MyClass1
{
    public void test()
    {
        StringBuilder one = new StringBuilder("testString1");
        Console.WriteLine("MyClass1: " + one);
        new MyClass2().test(one);
        Console.WriteLine(one); //testString1pilot is printed.
    }
}

class MyClass2
{
    public void test(StringBuilder two)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test method");
        Console.WriteLine(two);
        two.Append("pilot");
        Console.WriteLine(two);
    }
}
```

<sup>*</sup> Unless the method specifies a different mode of parameter passing, e.g. `out` or `ref`.

Comment: thanks. i ll check out with a `string-builder`. But, if the `references are passed by value` why don't we put a `ref` for the `stringBuilder`?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. You do not need to pass reference by reference  unless you want to change the reference itself. Passing reference by value is OK if you want to change the object without changing the reference to a different object. This is not possible with strings, because strings are immutable.

Answer (score 2):

> So, for all the reference types : when passing around their objects,
>   the changes should be reflected right ?

All reference types are `passed by reference` is not `true`.
all reference type or value types are `passed by value` by default.

if you want to pass any type as `reference types` you need to use `ref` or `out` keyword.

**Note:** `String` is a `immutable type` means `Strings` can not be changed.

That is the reason why you are not able to see the changes made in the called function.
You need to use `StringBuilder` to get back the changes.

`JonSteek` has explained about `Parmeter passing` well [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

Comment: okay, but if `all reference types or value types are passed by value by default` is true, why then for the `class objects` we do not require `ref` keyword ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: all objects or valu types are passed by value only , please check `Jo Steek` article here -> http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the fact that `String` is a reference type does not matter. The exact same thing would happen with any value type or even a mutable reference type (like a class).

This is because the parameter to a method normally acts like a local variable within the method. Changes made to the parameter are local to the method.

As you stated, the exception is when the parameter is `ref` or `out`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand the difference between the string which is a reference type and the variable itself that points to that object.

```
two = "pilot";
```

When you do this, you are creating a new string object and telling variable `two` to now point to this new string. The variable `one` still points to the original string, which is a different object.